# SQL Query not working Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: sql

Can someone please explain why this SQL Query isn't working for me?
I get this error:
Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS foodblog;

CREATE DATABASE foodblog;

USE foodblog;

CREATE TABLE posts (
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    titel varchar(255),
    datum DATETIME DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    img_url varchar(255),
    inhoud text,
    auteur_id int(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (auteur_id) REFERENCES auteurs(id)
);

CREATE TABLE auteurs (
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    auteur varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try re-ordering the queries. Because, when first query executes, the table `auteurs` would not be available. Here is the corrected code:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS foodblog;

CREATE DATABASE foodblog;

USE foodblog;

CREATE TABLE auteurs (
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    auteur varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE posts (
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    titel varchar(255),
    datum DATETIME DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    img_url varchar(255),
    inhoud text,
    auteur_id int(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (auteur_id) REFERENCES auteurs(id)
);
```